# Sharepoint oauth 2.0 API for access and refresh token

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharepoint, azure-active-directory, office365api

I am looking for the steps or procedure for sharepoint API that can provide me the access token and refresh token, So that I can fetch the sharepoint API's, As on MS docs it is mentioned that moving forward from 01 Oct 2022 the basic Auth menthod will be deprecated so I am implementing the oAuth 2.0 for that I need the sharepoint access and refresh token,

I have done some research from my side however I got the API for the access token, however when I am passing the access token to sharepoint API it is displying me the error code : " {"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."} "

Since the app was created in the azureAD as it is globally accessable to all the 365 applications. I do enabled the sharepoint permission over there also however it is not granting me the permission to access the app.

It will be great help if I got help in fixing the above mentioned error and the API for the refresh token of sharepoint so that I can fetch the sharepoint API with oauth 2.0.

The above mentioned api that I am creating is on node

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you used the token of the graph API to call the SharePoint API, so a 401 unauthorized error was returned.

To get an access token and refresh token for the SharePoint api you can use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). Before doing so, make sure that you have granted **SharePoint API** permissions for your application.

[image]

1. First obtain the authorization code in the browser:

```
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
    client_id={client id}
    &response_type=code
    &redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
    &response_mode=query
    &scope=https://{tenant name}.sharepoint.com/.default
    &state=12345
```

2. Use the authorization code to redeem the access token and refresh token:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, 
 Does this access token worked in sharepoint API's, 
as the alternative that I have followed is that, I do create the API in the sharepoint , I do get the access token from there , but when I am passing that access token, to share-point API's it is throwing me error code "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token type is not allowed."}",

And is there any change in sharepoint API's  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/connect-to-sharepoint.